# You tried to call count_params on ..., but the layer isn't built. TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I receive the following error in in Pyhotn 3 and TF 2.0.

"ValueError: You tried to call count_params on digits, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: digits.build(batch_input_shape)." at line new_model.summary().

what is the problem and how to solve it?

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='digits')
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='3_layer_mlp')
model.summary()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=64,
                    epochs=2)

model.save('saved_model', save_format='tf')
new_model = keras.models.load_model('saved_model')
new_model.summary()
```

Comment: I get this error when I load a model from a folder, it works properly on models that weren't loaded from disk.

Answer (score 1):

For 2.0 version Model can be saved in .h5 format, please use `model.save('my_model.h5')` while saving.

Please find the link of working [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/oanush/0a1db97731b201717003d19c29257f08/tf_nightly.ipynb).

Also issue seems to be resolved in the Latest TF-nightly version,as going forward 2.1 will be official version try using `pip install tf-nightly`

Find the link of working gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/oanush/4790590321eeaf5bf8be653b0454963c/tf_nightly.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error, and it solved after upgraded tf2.0 to tf2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using `tensorflow==2.0.0`. I tried running the same code using tensorflows nightly build (in my case `pip install tf-nightly==2.1.0.dev20191003`).

It worked on the nightly build but you may have to save the model again using the nightly build.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the model properly if there is not the last line of you codes, that is to say you just can not use summary here.

Comment: Is there any alternative to the last line of my code (new_model.summary())? I want to print the summary using this new model.